# Excel Macro Workbook_BeforeClose Specific Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks, one that we enter data in (Workbook A), and one we use for calculation (Workbook B).

When Workbook B is closed the following code runs, to reset it...

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Range("B2:B4,B6:B8,B10:B12,B14:B16,B18:B20,B22:B24,B26:B28,B30:B32").ClearContents
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

The problem is that if someone exits Excel while Workbook B is open, but Workbook A is in the foreground, you receive a Run-time error '1004'.

How can I change the macro to run the above code on Workbook B, regardless of what other workbooks are open or in the foreground?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've provided no indication what worksheet the range is on. Perhaps,

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
        .Range("B2:B4,B6:B8,B10:B12,B14:B16,B18:B20,B22:B24,B26:B28,B30:B32").ClearContents
        .Range("B2").Name = "openHere"
        Application.Goto Reference:="openHere"
        .Parent.Save
    End With
End Sub
```

You have to activate a worksheet in order to .Select a cell on it but Application.Goto can select a named cell. I've adjusted the code above to use a worbook-scope defined name and then Application.Goto that cell.

Comment: This gives me the error "Select method of Range class failed".

Comment: Yes, you need to activate a worksheet before you can select a cell on that worksheet. I've adjusted the code above but you might be better off just clearing the values and using Workbook_Open to select B2.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. Only thing is it no longers exits Excel upon completion, but I just call .Parent.Close and that solves that. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I've modified the .Select code into an Application.Goto above. This is likely a more robust method of guaranteeing that the workbook opens on Sheet1!B2.